# how to write a static function to find the available quantity in laravel 8?

Tags: php, laravel

I had the component model. This model had a  column as the quantity which means total quantity. I want to find the available quantity of components. So I want to create a static function in the component model.How to create it?

```
 <?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class ComponentItem extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $guarded = [];

    // Link the Component Type table
    public function component_type()
    {
        if ($this->component_type_id != null) return $this->belongsTo(ComponentType::class, 'component_type_id', 'id');
        return null;
    }

    public function inventoryCode()
    {
        return $this->component_type->inventoryCode() . "/" . $this->id;
    }

    // Return the relative URL of the thumbnail
    public function thumbURL()
    {
        if ($this->thumb != null) return '/img/component_items/' . $this->thumb;
        return null;
    }

    public function orders()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Order::class,ComponentItemOrder::class);   
    }

    public static function componentCount(){
        return 

    }

}
```

Comment: In pseudo-code, what is the formula? `remaining_quantity = total_quantity - (sum(orders.quantity))`?

Comment: we dont change the total quantity in database .remaining_quantity = total_quantity - (sum(orders.quantity)) yes

Comment: OK, and why do you want a _static_ function? How will the static function know which component to do the calculation on? I am not saying you shouldn't use a static function, just curious why that is a requirement.

Comment: This question needs more details and clarity, pls.